# create a loop to add new objects intances for a class in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I create a loop to create new instances of object/class in JavaScript?

I tried to do a loop like:

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    var name + i = new Objectname("name1","name2" etc);
}
```

But that did not work..

How can I do that in a loop.

Also I want to add the real dates for today and the next 3 days in those object one at a time.
Is that possible?

The code I have now just initiates a new instance and before the new instance i do:

```
tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
```

where tommorow is const tomorrow = new Date();
So that also needs to be in the loop I think....

My class is:

```
class weatherData {


    constructor(date, minTemp, maxTemp, wind) {
        this.date = date;
        this.minTemp = minTemp;
        this.maxTemp = maxTemp;
        this.wind = wind;
    }

    createRandom(date, averageTemp) {
        const windList = ['ZO', 'ZW', 'NO', 'NW', 'N', 'Z'];
        this.date = date;

        const maxRandom = averageTemp + 2;
        const minRandom = averageTemp - 2;

        this.minTemp = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxRandom) + minRandom;
        this.maxTemp = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxRandom) + this.minTemp;


        const size = windList.length;
        this.wind = windList[Math.floor(size * Math.random())];
    }
}
```

The function where i create new instances of weatherData:

```
function init() {
    // set new dates
    const today = new Date();
    const tomorrow = new Date();
    const nextday = new Date();
    const dayAfter = new Date();


    // create weather for today
    const weer1 = new weatherData(Date.now(), 5, 10, "ZO");
    weer1.createRandom(today, 10);

    // create weather for tomorrow
    tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
    const weer2 = new weatherData(tomorrow, 5, 10, "ZW");
    weer2.createRandom(tomorrow, 10);

    // create weather for next day
    nextday.setDate(today.getDate() + 2);
    const weer3 = new weatherData(nextday, 5, 15, 'ZO');
    weer3.createRandom(nextday, 10);

    // create weather for dayafter
    dayAfter.setDate(today.getDate() + 3);
    const weer4 = new weatherData(dayAfter, 6, 12, 'NO');
    weer4.createRandom(dayAfter, 9);

    let dates = [weer1, weer2, weer3, weer4];

    // loop through the dates to display weather in the table in my html file
    for (let i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById('day' + (i + 1)).innerHTML = dates[i].date.toDateString();
        document.getElementById('n' + (i + 5)).innerHTML = dates[i].maxTemp + '&deg';
        document.getElementById('n' + (i + 1)).innerHTML = dates[i].minTemp + '&deg';
        document.getElementById('w' + (i + 1)).innerHTML = dates[i].wind;


    }
}

init();
```

Comment: What is the object supposed to be? An HTML element?

Comment: You can't create dynamic variables like that. Put them in an array.